# What should I do before posting question so that my question shouldn't close?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, title

After writing title there are many suggestions of `Questions with similar titles`. I do see them but I realize that my question is not one of them though having some what similar title.

Then at bottom of every post there is written that ask your own question if you are not satisfied.

[image]

- So what should I do so that question will not close?
- Should I write all links that I have read but didn't got solution?

Update:

If title is matching with similar question, though giving so much clarifications People close question write away. How to avoid that?

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124991/how-can-i-show-my-flair-on-facebook-or-google) is closed because having somewhat same title though question is different and given enough explanation.

Comment: The question you've asked is *actually* offtopic for [metase]. We've been kind enough to give you a pointer as to where you should look at and what you should do,.

Comment: But why that question is closed as possible duplicate? Close it as offtopic. So that I understand it will not solved on MSO. Then whre should I ask questions about `flair`?

Comment: @SamStar: You mean to say [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124991/how-can-i-show-my-flair-on-facebook-or-google)

Comment: @SamStar didn't mention this was offtopic, "the question" refers to the question linked in his first comment

Comment: @Sathya Thanks, sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: I don't understand what the body of this question has to do with the title? Are you just ranting about the fact that your question got closed? Yes, if you ask a question that's a duplicate of another question, it will get closed. That's how the site works. You avoid your question getting closed as a duplicate **by not asking a duplicate question**. If it *does* get closed as a duplicate, you read the answers to the original question and go on about your business. And yes, Sathya is correct. We were nice enough to close the linked question as a duplicate, rather than just simply off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I write all links that I have read but didn't got solution?

Not if this means you don't post your own code along with a clear explanation...i.e. your question must **not** be

> I tried this and this and that but still not working, any help please?
>    (*)

This is the important part: your question needs to be well-formed, precise, has to show the efforts you made, and people need to understand clearly what you're asking and they should be in the position to provide a precise answer (not guessing, not asking a lot of clarifications in comment, not straying from your actual code)

If you fear dupes it's ok to point out what makes it different, I guess, but that doesn't need to be the main focus of your question.

**UPDATE:**

I apologize for seeing only now you actually refer to MSO and not SO. My suggestion refers specifically for the latter, but *mutatis mutandis* as a general rule they can apply to any site of the network

<sub>(*) In the tags I usually follow (php, e.g.) this format isn't uncommon</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The best piece of advice is to **ask a good question**. Jon Skeet has written a nice guide, [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), that will help you understand what separates an okay question from a great question. My favorite piece of advice is to read your question as if you wanted to answer it.

Read the question preview, too; the different formatting and line breaks can help you see things you miss in the monospaced editor box. (Seriously.)

It helps immensely to stay active and alert immediately after posting your question; people will ask questions in comments, *close as duplicate* votes will leave comments, and if you notice a duplicate that is not appropriate, you're around to explain the difference before the other four votes arrive. (If they found a question you're duplicating, then hurray! answers!)